# Struct with nested data using Decodable

Tags: swift, struct, decodable

I am consuming an API in Swift 4 using Alamofire. I am using structs to create Models of the data I wish to consume within that response and am confirming to Decodable.

My response looks like so...

```
    {  
       "pagination":{  
          "per_page":50,
          "items":3909,
          "page":1,
          "urls":{  
             "last":"https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=ed+rush&per_page=50&secret=foo&page=79&key=bar",
             "next":"https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=ed+rush&per_page=50&secret=foo&page=2&key=bar"
          },
          "pages":79
       },
       "results": []
    }
```

My models looks as follows...

```
struct SearchResults: Decodable {
    let pagination: SearchPagination
    let results: [SearchResult]
}

struct SearchResult: Decodable {
    let type: String
}

struct SearchPagination: Decodable {
    let per_page: Int
    let items: Int
    let page: Int
    let pages: Int
}
```

What I am trying to understand is how I would model pagination as `urls` is a nested object itself. Do I create a struct just for `urls` or am I missing something obvious here?

Perhaps a struct is not the best approach? I am coming from a JS background and structs feel very much like an interface in TypeScript however I am aware I may be missing something here.

Comment: You should create a `struct` for `urls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "rule" of `Decodable` is that any dictionary `{}` becomes a struct / class and each key becomes a property.

```
struct SearchPagination: Decodable {
    let per_page: Int
    let items: Int
    let page: Int
    let pages: Int
    let urls: URLData
}

struct URLData: Decodable {
    let last, next : URL
}
```